# Overlaying layers with different projections on Android

Tags: coordinate-system, android, reprojection-mathematics

Hello, I'm trying to show a map on Android. I'm using two map providers and am having trouble when converting geo point(lat/lon) to point in my viewport(x/y in pixels).

1) the first map provider used wgs84 -> EPSG:3395 projection 
2) the second map provider used EPSG:4326(wgs84) -> EPSG:3395 projection

In the  first case I can place any lat/lon correctly.
In the second case I have a discrepancy. I'm not sure about 2 km or more.

Why do I get this discrepancy if the projection of the providers is the same?

Please help me understand this.

**UPD:** This is the java code

```
        double 
        d = lon * Math.PI / 180, 
        m = lat * Math.PI / 180,
        l = 6378137,
        k = 0.0818191908426,// somebody explain what this constant means?
        f = k * Math.sin(m);

        double 
        h = Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + m / 2),
        j = Math.pow(Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + Math.asin(f) / 2), k), 
        i = h / j;

        double[] res = {l * d, l * Math.log(i)};
        return res;
```

This code works for wgs84 -> EPSG:3395.  I know thsi is the wrong approach but I just changed constant `k = 0.0818191908426` to my constant and it should work for some geographic region, but I think on the pole it will be wrong.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now have a suggestion for a Java library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are not the same.

[EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)

```
WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
Projected Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
Scope: Horizontal component of 3D system. Used by the GPS satellite navigation system and for NATO military geodetic surveying.
Last Revised: 2007-08-27
Area: World
```

[EPSG:3395](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/)

```
WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -80.0000, 180.0000, 84.0000
Projected Bounds: -20037508.3428, -15496570.7397, 20037508.3428, 18764656.2314
Scope: Very small scale mapping.
Last Revised: 2006-06-02
Area: World - between 80°S and 84°N
```

One is projected while the other is a geographic projection.

You're better off using existing map projection libraries instead of writing your own. You might want to try out the [Java Map Projection Library](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/) which is a partial port of the proj4 library mentioned by [BradHards](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8563/bradhards).

Comment: I can convert wgs84 -> EPSG:3395 see update how i do that. How i can convert EPSG:4326 -> EPSG:3395?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off using a projection tool, like proj4 (http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/ is a java version, but I haven't used it - I'd suggest http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/ as a safe alternative)

Comment: I tried to learn how it doing in library as OpenLayers. This library used proj4j. I tried to learn how it doing in proj4j but not to end. Ok looks like I have to take it completely to my android app ( thanks

Answer (score 2):

The value k = 0.0818191908426 is referred to as the First Eccentricity of the Earth.

This value is used in equations to convert between coordinate system values of position, such as lat-long-alt to ECEF coordinates.